# Grails Criteria - list contents

Tags: grails, criteria

These are my domain objects

```
User{
 hasMany = {roles: UserRole}
}

UserRole{
  User user
  Role role
}

Role{
  String authority
}
```

I need to find users based on their Role. For that I am trying to use the following criteria:

```
  def role_admin = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')
  def criteria = new DetachedCriteria(User).build {
    roles{
      role{
        idEq(role_admin.id)
      }
    }
  }

  result.users = criteria.list(params)
  result.total = criteria.count()
```

The above will always return one result, even though I have verified by looking at the database directly that there should be more results. The `params` passed to list are correct, but I tried removing them just to be sure. I can't see what is wrong with the above, any suggestions ?

I also tried this

```
roles{
    role{
        eq("authority","ROLE_ADMIN")
    }
}
```

But it is throwing exception:

> Unknown column 'role_alias2_.authority' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me:

```
def criteriaUsers = UserRole.createCriteria()
def users =  criteriaUsers.listDistinct{
                eq("role", role_admin)
             }.user
```

Side note: from the nomenclature of your classes it looks like you are using spring-security-core plugin. In my humble opinion the `hasMany = [roles: UserRole]` is redundant as the association User - Role is already being modeled in the `UserRole` class.

Comment: There are more items in criteria which I removed for debugging, that's why I go for criteria

Comment: I have edited my answer and I have used criteria now.

Comment: Right, this does work. Any clue why it fails when trying to query on `authority` field?

Comment: I have no idea as apparently your syntax looks fine. it would be worth enabling a fine grained logging to see your sql queries (in DataSource.groovy): `datasource { ... logSql = true}`. I hope my original post did answer your question, by the way.

Comment: Yes I have end up using the eq("role", role_admin) part. Thank you